# Deterministic integrals involving a Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to work out the following two integrals involving a standard Brownian motion started at $W_0 = 0$.

The first expression is bewildering me a bit, since it seems like somehow the Itô isometry is involved and would help me work the expectation.
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T\,W_t\,dt \right)^2\right]
$$
Secondly, it seems like to prove the following inequality it could be useful to reach an expression resulting in $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$, but I am not sure how to do it.
$$
\mathbb P\left(\int_0^1\,W_t\,dt > \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \right)
$$

Any help is welcome!

Comment: @ Adam : Think about Integration by Parts formula, then you should arrive to a sum of Gaussian unless mistaken (I haven't the calculations though too lazy for that). Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge Sorry but this is muuuch more direct.

Comment: @ Did : No need to be sorry, if it has already been solved in an old post then everything is fine. Best regards